# Variable not storing?

Tags: ios, swift, viewwithtag

I am currently developing a tactical screen app where one can access a database to add to add players into their screens. The database is working fine, I am now trying to pass over player information into the selected position. The player information passes over fine, but I am now having trouble with trying to implement that player information into the selected position:

```
var selectedP: Int?

@IBAction func selectAPlayer(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.selectedP = sender.view!.tag
    //print (selectedP!)
}
```

Above is the method which demonstrates how I am trying to save the selected position's tag with `selectedP`, so I can access its subviews. The correct tag prints out in the above method. However, when I try to call it in another method, the variable returned is always nil. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Here is the method where I try to call the `selectedP` variable:

```
func setPlayer () {
        //print(selectedP!)
    }
```

Simply printing `selectedP` crashes the program as it is obviously equivalent to `nil`. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

**I must note that the `setPlayer()` method is called by a segue from another class which is essentially a `View Player` class. This is shown as a popover in the application. I'm not sure that if you call a popoverController the variables essentially get restored?**

Comment: try any one at a time or both this `var selectedP: Int!` and `self.selectedP = sender.tag`. I am just saying I haven't tried it practically.

Comment: @creatando setPlayer should be called in your IBAction you get your value in variable only when you perform your action.Before that you can not call setPlayer method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to pass over the variable to the popover, and then back. Here's how I did it in a more generic way:

```
    let viewController = "addPopover"
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController) as? PopoverViewController
// Above we get the popover, below we set a variable in that popover's class.
    vc?.varThatNeedsToBeStored = sender.view!.tag
```

Then in my prepare segue method in the popover class:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let nextScene = segue.destination as? TacticalCentreViewController
    nextScene?.varThatNeedsToBeStored = varThatNeedsToBeStored
}
```

This now returns the correct tag value.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you set your variable as self.selectedP, not selectedP. I'm not familiar with swift, but this concept is fairly universal. In python:

```
class foo():
    def setBar():
        self.bar = True
    print(str(self.bar)) #prints True
    print(str(bar))      #throws error
```

Comment: I tried it before adding `self.`, didn't seem to make a difference unfortunately.